# Moving 1M of files on 5M

Tags: 16.04, mv

Is there a command line to move 1M of files from a directory with 5M of files?

I tried:

```
sudo mv `ls | head -1000000` <destination>
```

But I get this message: -bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Argument list too long

Thank you.

Comment: rsync is not an option because the total is like 1To, and I do not have enough space to copy them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **shellscript** file with a list of commands for single files. It will not be very fast, but this way you will avoid the problem with a too long argument list.

- Try first with less than 1 million commands (for example 15), in order to check that it works correctly.
- Modify `/path/to/sourcedir` and `/path/to/targetdir` to match your actual directories.

---

```
find /path/to/sourcedir -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "mv \"%p\" /path/to/targetdir\n" | head -n 15 > myscript
```

Make the script executable

```
chmod ugo+x myscript
```

Run the script

```
./myscript
```

Comment: I like your idea @sudodus! I was trying to dev a script with a "while". It goal will be to move every files starting by 1 into a directory called 1 and etc...

Comment: @Nico, Please tell me, if you want more help (and in that case with what details).

Comment: My script seems to work fine. It takes time, but should be ok :D Thanks again.

Comment: @Nico, You are welcome, I'm glad that your script is working well :-)